# Iterating through a dict, list in python

Tags: java, python, list, dictionary

Now that I know how to iterate through a dict, I need to know how to iterate through a list and be able to print each customer, account and transaction. I have 3 classes Customer, Account, and Transaction. Within the Customer class, I put a list to hold Account objects and within the Account class, I have a list to hold Transaction objects. Near the end of this code, I have a for loop iterating through the map, but when I try to iterate through the list, it doesn't seem to work. It is most likely through my own error.

```
class Customer(object):
'''Main Constructor'''
def__init__(self,CNumber=1,CName="A",CAddress="A",CCity="A",CState="A",CZipCode=1,CPhone="1",Account=[]):
    self.CNumber = CNumber
    self.CName = CName
    self.CAddress = CAddress
    self.CCity = CCity
    self.CState = CState
    self.CZipCode = CZipCode
    self.CPhone = CPhone
    self.Account = Account

dict = {}
c = Customer.Customer("1111","Jake","Main St","Happy Valley","CA","96687","8976098765")
dict[c.getCNumber()] = c
c = Customer.Customer("2222","Paul","3342 CherrySt","Seatle","WA","98673","9646745678")
dict[c.getCNumber()] = c

a = Account.Account("1111",True,0.00,500.00)
dict[c.getCNumber()].AddAccount(a)
a = Account.Account("2222",True,0.00,500.00)
dict[c.getCNumber()].AddAccount(a)
a = Account.Account("3333",False,0.02,10000.00)
dict[c.getCNumber()].AddAccount(a)
a = Account.Account("4444",False,0.02,10000.00)
dict[c.getCNumber()].AddAccount(a)

for key in sorted(dict.keys()):
    print("***Customer***")
    print("Customer Number: " + dict[key].getCNumber())
    print(dict[key].getCName())
    print(dict[key].getCAddress())
    print(dict[key].getCCity() + ", " + dict[key].getCState() + " " + dict[key].getCZipCode())
    for key1 in dict[key].getAccount()[key1]:
        print("\t***Account***")
        print("\tAccount Number: " + a.getANumber())
        print("\t" + a.getAType())
        print("\t" + a.getAInterestRate())
```

If you need more info, let me know. I need it to print each customer (which is within the dict) and every Account associated with that customer. In the future I will need every transaction associated with that account. I did it in Java (and it works) as follows:

```
        for (Customer c : customerMap.values()) {
        // Print the customer name, address, etc.
        System.out.println("\n**********Customer**********");
        System.out.println("Customer Number: " + c.getCustomerNumber());
        System.out.println(c.getCustomerName());
        System.out.println(c.getCustomerAddress());
        System.out.println(c.getCustomerCity() + ", "
                + c.getCustomerState() + " " + c.getCustomerZipCode());
        System.out.println(c.getCustomerPhone());
        for (Account a : c.getAllAccounts()) {
            // Print the account balance, id, type
            System.out.println("\t**********Account**********");
            System.out.println("\tAccount Number: " + a.getAccountNumber());
            if (a.getAccountType() == true) {
                System.out.println("\tAccount Type: Checking");
            } else {
                System.out.println("\tAccount Type: Savings");
            }
            System.out.println("\tAccount Balance: " + a.getBalance());
            System.out.println("\tInterest Rate: " + a.getInterestRate());
            for (Transaction t : a.getAllTransactions()) {
                // Go through the transactions of this account
                System.out.println("\t\t**********Transactions**********");
                System.out.println("\t\tTransaction Date: " + t.getDate());
                System.out.println("\t\tTransaction Amount: "
                        + t.getAmount());
                if (t.getDebitOrCredit() == true) {
                    System.out.println("\t\tDebit or Credit: Credit");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("\t\tDebit or Credit: Debit");
                }
                System.out.println("\t\tMemo: " + t.getMemo());

            }// for
        }// for
    }// for
```

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: I guess where I am getting hung up is in this code: for key1 in dict[key].getAccount()[key1]: What syntax needs to be changed?

Comment: for key1 in dict[key].getAccount():

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Iterating over a `dict`'s items:**

```
>>> d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
>>> for k, v in d.items():
...     print "{}={}".format(k, v)
... 
a=1
c=3
b=2
```

**Iterating over a `dict`'s keys:**

```
>>> for k in d.keys():
...     print k
... 
a
c
b
```

**Iterating over a `dict`'s values:**

```
>>> for v in d.values():
...     print v
... 
1
3
2
```

**Iterating over a `list`:**

```
>>> xs = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for x in xs:
...     print x
... 
1
2
3
>>>
```

**Note(s):**

- DO NOT name your variables `dict` or `list` as they shadow the builtins and could cause you problems.

Answer (score 1):

***To iterate through a list***, you can do the following:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

for item in a:
    print item

1
2
3
4
5
```

the word 'item' above was arbitrary, I could have used pretty much anything:

```
for i in a:
    print i+1

2
3
4
5
6
```

but essentially, it's:

```
for element in listname:
    do something
```

There are other ways, but here are some docs: http://www.diveintopython.net/file_handling/for_loops.html

***To iterate over a dict***

you can do:

```
for key in d.keys(): # iterates through a list of the dict d's keys
    some code..

for value in d.values(): #iterates through a list of dict d's values
    some code..

for key, value in d.items(): #iterates through a list of key/value pairs from d
    code code...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this line of code:

```
    for key1 in dict[key].getAccount()[key1]:
```

You can't define `key1` with a reference to`key1`

Comment: If `dict[key].getAccount()` returns a list, then the code `for key1 in dict[key].getAccount()` will let you iterate over every account in that list using the reference `key1`. In the loop body, replace references to `a.` with `key1.`

Comment: I'm still not getting the itorator to work. getAccount() returns the list that I am working with. I think the error is within the syntax of retreiving a list